Cannot download unlisted Odysee video using Python
I am using the below code to fetch the contentUrl of an unlisted video on Odysee.
import requests, ast

def getVideoMetadata(url,timeout=7):
    return ast.literal_eval(requests.get(url,timeout=timeout).text.split('<script type="application/ld+json">')[1].split("</script>")[0])

stream = getVideoMetadata(link) #link contains the shareable link of the video
print(stream['contentUrl'])

However, the contentUrl shows the below message on screen, when pasted in browser.

edge credentials missing

Below is a snapshot of the webpage.

Is there any workaround to download an unlisted video if the shareable link is available?
